# Using Middleware in Blazor WebAssembly 3.2 Preview

Tags: c#, localization, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazored

Blazor WebAssembly 3.2 Preview uses a new way to start the program that does not use Startup.cs.

I have a custom middleware that analyzes the requests before processing them, which I cannot configure with this new version.

A simplified version of the middleware running ok with the old way:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
              //All the services...
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseMyMiddleware();

            //more config...
        }
    }
```

```
public static class MyMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
        }
    }
```

```
public class MyMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
           if (httpContext.Request.Host.Host.Contains("test"))
               Console.Writeline("test");
           else
               Console.Writeline("prod");
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
```

Following the specifications of the release document of this version (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-1-release-now-available/) I have managed to reconfigure all the DI services but I can't get the middleware working.

I have tried in many ways and it does not work, but I do not want to fill the question with code that does not work and it seems better to leave you with this very simplified code that works ok with the previous version so that you can suggest changes from there.

I even tried using StartupFilter to not use Startup.cs as suggested on the page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-services-without-startup), but it doesn't work either, I guess it's due to Blazor WASM.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Blazor WebAssembly does not use middleware. There is no pipeline.

Comment: Hi Henk, thanks for your comment.
There is a library that may help to understand what I need.
This is a localization middleware library that has already converted to the new version.
If you compare branch preview6 (https://github.com/Blazored/Localisation/tree/preview6) with the master (https://github.com/Blazored/Localisation) you will see the changes.
Unfortunately I couldn't get my middleware to work by making similar changes.

Comment: And where is the middleware in that lib or in the samples?

Comment: I think you are right Henk, he changed the form of startup.cs but he did not have the usemiddleware in the previous version. Really sorry...
So if I can't use middleware, do you know how could I capture the host data of each request? Maybe using old httphandle ?
Thanks

Comment: The browser is truly the host of a Blazor WASM app, as this is where your code is being executed, not the web server that downloaded the code in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally submitted that too soon! I was going to suggest that you try parsing the URL in the browser location bar to look for yourproductiondomain.com or yourtestdomain.com to find out which environment the app was originally served up from.